# Change the color of the geom_bar() in ggplot2 inside an R function

Tags: r, dataframe, function, ggplot2

Using the toy `DATA` below, I'm trying to have `my_function()` to **white out (i.e., not show)** the bars in the `geom_bar` ONLY when the y axis value for a bar is < .5 or > .95. Otherwise, simply fill the color based on the value of `X` variable that is, `fill = X`.

For my purposes, I'm using the `after_stat(count)/ sapply(PANEL, \(x) sum(count[PANEL == x]))` to compute the y axis values internally.

Is there a way to achieve my goal (or somehow suppress those bars)?

*Here is what I tried without success:*

```
library(tidyverse)
library(rlang)

DATA <- structure(list(Year = c(2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 2016, 2016, 
2016, 2016, 2016), X = c("Dissatisfied", "Dissatisfied", 
"Dissatisfied", "Dissatisfied", "Dissatisfied", "Satisfied", 
"Dissatisfied", "Dissatisfied", "Satisfied", "Dissatisfied")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-10L))


my_function <- function(data=DATA, x=X, cols = vars(Year), fill=X){
  
  ggplot(data) + aes(x= !!ensym(x), y=after_stat(count)/ sapply(PANEL, \(x) sum(count[PANEL == x]))
                   , fill=ifelse( round(after_stat(count)/ sapply(PANEL, \(x) sum(count[PANEL == x])) * 100, 2) < 5| 
round(after_stat(count)/ sapply(PANEL, \(x) sum(count[PANEL == x])) * 100, 2) > 95, "white"
                                  , "fill")) + ## what to use for `fill=` here?
    geom_bar()  +
    facet_grid(cols=cols) +
    theme(legend.title=element_blank())
  
}
###### EXAMPLE OF USE:
my_function()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option would be to use `stage` to map `X` on `fill` and do an *after_stat* calculation to set the `fill` to `NA` for columns you want to white out. Additionally, we have to set the color assigned to `NA` via `na.value` and if desired/needed drop the `NA` values from the legend using `breaks=`. Finally, note that I use `ave` to compute the percentage share and use a helper function for the computation.

```r
library(tidyverse)

my_function <- function(data = DATA, x = X, cols = vars(Year)) {
  
  helper <- \(count, PANEL) ave(count, PANEL, FUN = \(x) x / sum(x))
  
  ggplot(data) +
    aes(
      x = !!ensym(x),
      y = after_stat(helper(count, PANEL)),
      fill = stage(X,
        after_stat =
          if_else(
            helper(count, PANEL) < .05 |
              helper(count, PANEL) > .95,
            NA,
            fill
          )
      )
    ) +
    geom_bar() +
    scale_fill_discrete(
      breaks = \(x) x[!is.na(x)],
      na.value = "white"
    ) +
    facet_grid(cols = cols) +
    theme(legend.title = element_blank())
}

my_function()
```

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately, I get an error from your function: `ℹ Error occurred in the 1st layer.
Caused by error in 'if_else()':
! 'false' must be a logical vector, not a character vector.`. Additionally, note that I added a `fill=` argument to `my_function()` in my original post.

Comment: Looks like you are running on an older version of `dplyr`. Mine is `1.1.4`. Besides updating you could (probably) fix that by using `if_else(..., NA_character_, ...)`.